# How to get allocated gpus for node in kubernetes[with kubernetes-client java api]

Tags: kubernetes

I want to get available gpus[nvidia.com/gpu] in kubernetes cluster, and i now get total gpu from NodeAPI, but how to get allocated gpus from client api??
like `kubectl describe node` result:

```
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests   Limits
  --------           --------   ------
  cpu                350m (8%)  0 (0%)
  memory             70Mi (0%)  170Mi (1%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)     0 (0%)
  nvidia.com/gpu     1          1
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of allocatable GPUs you can use something like:

```
from kubernetes import client, config
config.load_incluster_config
c = client.CoreV1Api()
nodes = c.list_node().to_dict().get("items") # You will need enough previleges to execute this command
allocatable_nvidia_gpus = 0
for node in nodes:
    if not "status" in node:
        continue
    if not "allocatable" in node["status"]:
        continue
    if "nvidia.com/gpu" in node["status"]["allocatable"]:
        allocatable_nvidia_gpus += int(node["status"]["allocatable"]["nvidia.com/gpu"]
```

and to count allocated GPUs you can use something like:

```
allocated_gpus = 0
pods = c.list_namespaced_pod(namespace=settings.NAMESPACE).to_dict().get("items")
for pod in pods:
    if not "spec" in pod:
        continue 
    if not "containers" in pod["spec"]:
        continue
    for container in pod["spec"]["containers"]:
        if not "resources" in container:
            continue
        if not "limits" in container["resources"]:
            continue
        if container["resources"]["limits"] != None:
            if "nvidia.com/gpu" in container["resources"]["limits"]:
                allocated_gpus += int(container["resources"]["limits"]["nvidia.com/gpu"])
```